# Create a new project with xcode 4.3.2 without a storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I am looking for a good tutorial that shows step-by-step how to do create a new project with xcode 4.3.2 without using the storyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: It's very similar to any of the millions of tutorials that are already out there. When you start the project, uncheck the storyboard option.

Comment: Does generating UI with XIB is the same of doing so with the storyboard?

Comment: It's similar - a storyboard is really a collection of connected xib files, with the transitions between them already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the links that when you create any project it gives you the options which you want for your project just look at the below link

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html

hope this helps